# What encryption is this?

Tags: encryption

7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b

This is 123456, I don't know what kind of encryption it is and all the passwords are saving as it in my database so i need to know

Comment: you could have also googled this string and received an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an unsalted SHA-1 hash:

```
$ echo -n 123456 | sha1sum
7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b  -
$
```

This is a one-way operation, a hash, which is not technically "encryption" as it can't be decrypted.

Comment: This answer also pretty much says "whatever system this is from, throw it out and never look back". About the only thing that could be worse, I think, would be an unsalted MD5 hash.

Comment: Agree with @MichaelKjörling - unsalted SHA1 is a very weak method of password storage.